# Centos 7 install gcj-jdk

Tags: centos, yum

How do I install gcj-jdk on Centos 7?
I want to install a software for which it says in prerequisites that you have to have gcj-jdk installed. Otherwise, it won't work. However, I cannot find it in the packages via `yum`. So, how do I do that?

Comment: Try `yum install gcj`? or `gcc-java`

Comment: Doesn't work. It says `No package gcj available.`  resp. `No package gcc-java available.`

Comment: Have a look over [here](https://pkgs.org/download/java-gcj-compat), looks like the package does not exist in Centos 7 repos.

Answer (score 1):

gcc-java and gcj are both deprecated.  Ubuntu and some distributions support the older versions but RedHat and CentOS do not.  If having gcj is important to you, need to switch to Ubuntu.